# Missing Full Text Index System View In Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-indexing, system-views

I've been reading about the system view: `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document`
[on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280607(v=SQL.100).aspx) but can't find the view in my 2008 database.  Anyone know if it should be there by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a TVF not a View.

If you mean you can't see it in Object Explorer look in the master database under `Programmability -> Functions -> System Functions -> Table Valued Functions`